# Getting the highest value column row as the joined row

Tags: sql, left-join

I have the SQL statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM `assocMessages`
LEFT JOIN `messageThreads` ON `messageThreads`.`threadID` = `assocMessages`.`threadID` 
LEFT JOIN `messages` ON `messageThreads`.`threadID` = `messages`.`threadID` 
WHERE `assocMessages`.`accountID` =1
GROUP BY `messageThreads`.`threadID` 
ORDER BY `messages`.`messageSent` DESC
```

which is designed to fetch a list of `message threads` that are has the current user associated with it. It also is designed to fetch the most recent `message` that is associated with the `message threads` found, however, it is only showing the first message sent on the found `message thread`. I added the statement `ORDER BY messages.messageSent DESC`, however, regardless of it being there, or the direction being `ASC` or `DESC`, it only shows the first `message` sent. Does anyone know what I could do? I am trying to keep it to a single SQL statement to prevent encountering the n+1 selects problem.

**EDIT**

I have just tried reversing the tables, so it initially has `FROM messages` and the `assocMessages` table is joined later

**EDIT**

assocMessages:

```
+-----------+----------+
| accountID | threadID |
+-----------+----------+
| 1         | 1        |
+-----------+----------+
| 2         | 1        |
+-----------+----------+
```

messageThreads:

```
+----------+---------------------+
| threadID | threadCreatedOn     |
+----------+---------------------+
| 1        | 2013-05-01 12:00:00 |
+----------+---------------------+
```

messages:

```
+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
| messageID | threadID | accountID | messageBody | messageSent         |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
| 1         | 1        | 1         | First Hi    | 2013-05-01 12:00:00 |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
| 2         | 1        | 2         | Second Hi   | 2013-05-01 12:01:00 |
+-----------+----------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+
```

So, when queried, it will return a list of threads (that `accountID` 1 is enrolled in), with the most recent `message`, which is `messageID` 2 that was sent by `accountID` 2

What is returned:

```
+-----------+----------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
| accountID | threadID | threadCreated       | messageID | messageBody | messageSent         | threadID | accountID |
+-----------+----------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
| 1         | 1        | 2013-05-01 12:00:00 | 1         | First Hi    | 2013-05-01 12:00:00 | 1        | 1         |
+-----------+----------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
```

What should be returned:

```
+-----------+----------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
| accountID | threadID | threadCreated       | messageID | messageBody | messageSent         | threadID | accountID |
+-----------+----------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
| 1         | 1        | 2013-05-01 12:00:00 | 2         | Second Hi   | 2013-05-01 12:01:00 | 1        | 2         |
+-----------+----------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
```

What is returned if I remove `group by`:

```
+-----------+----------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
| accountID | threadID | threadCreated       | messageID | messageBody | messageSent         | threadID | accountID |
+-----------+----------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
| 1         | 1        | 2013-05-01 12:00:00 | 2         | Second Hi   | 2013-05-01 12:01:00 | 1        | 2         |
+-----------+----------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
| 1         | 1        | 2013-05-01 12:00:00 | 1         | First Hi    | 2013-05-01 12:00:00 | 1        | 1         |
+-----------+----------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+---------------------+----------+-----------+
```

The first `accountID`s are the same because they are being returned from the `messageThreads` association

**FINAL EDIT (for the moment)**

When I drop the `GROUP BY messageThreads.threadID`, it shows all the messages in every thread

Comment: Are you sure there are multiples where `assocMessages.accountID=1`

Comment: You are grouping by `messageThreads.threadID` and putting a condition `WHERE assocMessages.accountID =1`, first question are you sure you have many thread id for accountID=1 ?
Could you display more details ?  table structure and result details

Comment: There are multiple `accountID`s within the thread, which is why it is fetching any threads that contain the current user, then to fetch the most recent message from the thread

Comment: @cgoddard Based on your sample data what is the desired result of the query?

Comment: @bluefeet I have updated the question with the returned rows (what is show, what I want it to show, and when `GROUP BY` is remove)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think part of your problem is the way that MySQL applies the `GROUP BY`. MySQL [extends the GROUP BY function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) allowing items in the select list to be excluded from both an aggregate function and the GROUP BY. This extension can lead to unexpected results.

I think the following will give you the result that you want:

```
SELECT a.accountId,
  a.threadId,
  mt.threadCreatedOn,
  m.messageId,
  m.messageBody,
  m.messageSent,
  m.accountId messageAccountId
FROM `assocMessages` a
INNER JOIN `messageThreads` mt
  ON mt.`threadID` = a.`threadID` 
LEFT JOIN
(
  select m1.*
  from messages m1
  inner join
  (
    select max(messageSent) messageSent,
      threadId
    from messages
    group by threadid
  ) m2
    on m1.threadid = m2.threadid
    and m1.messageSent = m2.messageSent
) m
  ON mt.`threadID` = m.`threadID` 
WHERE a.`accountID` =1
ORDER BY m.`messageSent` DESC;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c39d/21)

Answer (score 0):

I was slightly confused by what you're actually asking, however take a look at this:

```
SELECT `assocMessages`.*, `messageThreads`.`threadCreatedOn`, `messages`.`messageBody`, `messages`.`messageSent` 
FROM `assocMessages`
LEFT JOIN `messageThreads` ON `messageThreads`.`threadID` = `assocMessages`.`threadID`
LEFT JOIN `messages` ON `messageThreads`.`threadID` = `messages`.`threadID` AND `assocMessages`.`accountID`=`messages`.`accountID`
WHERE `assocMessages`.`accountID` =1
ORDER BY `messages`.`messageSent` DESC
```

Is this what you're trying to do? I modded messages to have

```
messageID   threadID    accountID   messageBody     messageSent
1           1           1           First Hi    2013-05-01 12:00:00
2           1           2           Second Hi   2013-05-01 12:01:00
3           1           1           Third Message   2013-05-01 12:02:00
```

and the SQL query result is:

```
accountID   threadID    threadCreatedOn     messageBody     messageSent
1           1           2013-05-01 12:00:00     Third Message   2013-05-01 12:02:00
1           1           2013-05-01 12:00:00     First Hi    2013-05-01 12:00:00
```

Comment: that one will only give the most recent message from the current user

Comment: If you only want the most recent, just add
    LIMIT 1
to the end of the query

Comment: Sorry, I've reread what you actually wanted and most recent from EVERY thread associated with a user. You're right, my bad. Good luck to you!

Comment: don't worry, tis ok, the solution is the query above and it works perfectly :)